# HAProxy TLS/SSL with Apache Pulsar

Tags: ssl, haproxy, apache-pulsar

I am using HAProxy as a TCP load balancer in front of a series of Apache Pulsar Proxy. I am trying to enable SSL/TLS encryption for my connection to Apache Pulsar cluster. For testing I am using a let's encrypt cert. Unfortunately, when I am trying to connect to the admin REST API of the Apache Pulsar broker through the HAProxy host, I am met with a warning about a insecure connection or connection refused.

Currently my HAProxy config for an SSL connection on port 8443 looks like this:

```
listen https_frontend
    bind :8443 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_url/haproxy_cert.pem
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    balance roundrobin
    server proxy1 10.0.0.X:8443 check maxconn 10000
    server proxy2 10.0.0.X:8443 check maxconn 10000
    server proxy3 10.0.0.X:8443 check maxconn 10000
    server proxy4 10.0.0.X:8443 check maxconn 10000
```

Do the Apache Pulsar proxies and brokers need their own certs as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are forwarding a SSL/TLS port on HAProxy to the SSL/TLS port on the Pulsar proxy/broker (8443), assuming you are using the default port for that on the Pulsar proxy/broker. If you don't want to have to configure certificates on Pulsar proxy/broker for SSL/TLS, you should configure HAProxy to send to the plain-text port on the Pulsar proxy/broker (80).